# Tinyxml: Problem updating code from diamonback to electric

Tags: ros, ros-diamondback, tinyxml, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I have a node that is using tinyxml to read and xml file.

That node works perfectly in diamonback, but I need to update it to electric, so I follow the instrucionts in http://www.ros.org/wiki/tinyxml :

1- Remove tinyxml dependency in manifest.

2- Change the header file which is included... Now is just:

`#include <tinyxml.h>`

3- Link against the library in the CMakeLists...

`target_link_libraries(master tinyxml)`

It compiles without problems, but when running the node, the behaviour is not the expected and gives some errors.

It seems like the function Value() is not behaving the same way it was in diamondback...

Do you think I should do any change more than what I have already done? Or maybe the library that was using diamondback and the one which installs electric are slightly different?

I will appreciate any help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34202/tinyxml:-problem-updating-code-from-diamonback-to-electric./) by [Jep](https://answers.ros.org/users/2367/jep/) on ROS Answers with karma: 195 on 2012-05-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I finally solved this by myself.

It was a problem with a C define in tinyxml library.

If you have some problems with the tinyxml library make sure that TIXML_USE_STL is defined in the .h file.

```
#ifndef TIXML_USE_STL
    #define TIXML_USE_STL
#endif
```

---

Originally posted by [Jep](https://answers.ros.org/users/2367/jep/) with karma: 195 on 2012-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1